# How to store Spark Streaming Checkpoint Location into S3?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset, spark-checkpoint

I am interested in a Spark Streaming app (Spark v2.3.2) that sources S3 parquet data and writes parquet data to S3. The app's data frame stream makes use of `groupByKey()` and `flatMapGroupsWithState()` to make use of the `GroupState`.

Is it possible to configure this to use an **s3** checkpoint location? For example:

```
val stream = myDataset.writeStream
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", s3DataDestination)
    .option("checkpointLocation", s3CheckpointPath)
    .option("truncate", false)
    .option(Trigger.Once)
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
stream.start().awaitTermination()
```

I confirmed the above is able to successfully write data to the `s3DataDestination`.

However, an exception is thrown when writing to the s3 checkpoint location:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error committing version 1 into HDFSStateStore[id=(op=0, part=9), dir=s3://<my_s3_location>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$HDFSBackedStateStore.commit(...)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename s3://.../checkpoint/state/0/9/temp... to s3://.../checkpoint/state/0/9/1.delta
```

Would this require a custom implementation of a S3 `StateStoreProvider`? Or, does the checkpoint location need to be written into HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the frequency of concurrency of writes and reads is too high. 
AWS S3 does not provide such kind of feature.

Solution :

- We had to switch to local mounted persistent disk for the Spark check pointing
- S3Guard : This will make the S3 reads and writes more consistent (Note : It is experimental and I personally have never seen it in action)
- Use HDFS